# Import problems in FastAPI-based backend with Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-import, fastapi

I am running a FastAPI-based backend and I am running into the following error:

```
File "/app/main.py", line 6, in <module>
backend-backend-1  |     from app.api.api_v1.api import api_router
backend-backend-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

This is an import error. The file structure is like:

```
--backend
|---app
|------models
|------schemas
|------etc
|------main.py
```

My dockerfile for the backend is like:

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app/

ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

When I print the `sys.path` I get the following output:

['', '/usr/local/bin', '/app', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

`/app`is there. Do you have any idea what may be causing the problem? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You're copying _the contents_ of the `app` directory into `/app`, but you're using `/app` in sys.path - effectively losing the first level. You probably want to copy the contents of `backend` into `app` instead (depending on what the contents are) - or into `/app/app`.

Comment: Sorry. Did not understand. If I have a module called "app" with every other package inside (models, schemas, etc) that is in the PYTHONPATH, why can't I access it and am getting the module not found error?